# Asking about reason of convergence of series on Apostol Mathematical analysis ( Chapter - Lebesgue Integral)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

While studying Apostol Mathematical analysis I am unable to find reason of following argument whose picture follows :
[image]

> In first line of last paragraph can someone please tell how author wrote " the series on right being convergent " ? Can someone please tell how this particular series is convergent?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the fourth equation of your image
$$n^{-s}\Gamma(s) = \int_0^{+\infty}e^{-nx}x^{s-1}ds$$
We want to know the nature of the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-nx}x^{s-1}ds$ or, equivalently, of the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}n^{-s}\Gamma(s)$. Since $\Gamma(s)\in\mathbb{R}$ is constant, this series converges if, and only if $\sum_{n\geq 1}n^{-s}$ converges. It is a classical result in analysis that this last series converges if, and only if, $s>1$ (this is reminded at the beginning of the penultimate paragraph of your image).

Answer (score 0):

It is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-s}\Gamma(s)=\Gamma(s)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}$$

Comment: Worth emphasizing $s>1.$

Comment: Yes, it is in line above.